# How to retrieve JSON value in BASH (automatic version in git commit)?

Tags: json, git, bash, github

How can I retrieve the `version` attribute from the following json file AND use it in a BASH script?..

**file package.json**

```
{
  "name": "myapp",
  "version": "0.0.1"
}
```

**desired script: bpush.sh**

```
#!/bin/bash
gulp bump
git add -A
eval $pkg_ver = getjson('./package.json', 'version')
git commit -a -m "$pkg_ver"
git push origin master
```

**Obviously, the `getjson()` function is invalid.**  That is what I'm trying to figure out.

**Edit: Final Result**
Here's what I used, thanks to the folks below...

```
#!/bin/sh

pkg_ver=$(jq '.version' package.json)
pkg_ver=${pkg_ver//\"/}
git add -A
git commit -a -m $pkg_ver
git push origin master
```

Comment: `pkg_ver=$(tr -cd '[0-9.]' < package.json)`?

Comment: There is no need for `eval` here; just use `pkg_ver=$(...)`, where `...` will be provided by an acceptable answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If your json file is more complex then I would suggest to use jq - [link](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/)

```
pkg_ver=$(jq '.version' package.json)
```

However, if you have only this two items then maybe using sed, awk or tr would be easier.

Comment: Maybe `$pkg_ver = $(jq '.version' <package.json)` ?

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin Yes, I forget about the file.

Comment: Happens, we could tell what you intended to do. Good job on `jq` recommendation.

Comment: Thanks, guys.  I used `jq` and stripped off the quotes.  (See the edit above.)

Answer (score 4):

Why not using [javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript) itself from a [bash](/questions/tagged/bash) *here-doc* ? :)

Remember, JS stands for *JavaScript Object Notation*

```
pkg_ver=$(
    node<<EOF
    var obj = $(<package.json);
    console.log(obj.version);
EOF
)
```

Replace `node` by the `nodejs` executable or [rhino](/questions/tagged/rhino) if you don't have `node`

Or as a [bash](/questions/tagged/bash) *one-liner* :

```
node <<< "var obj = $(<package.json); console.log(obj.version);"
```

Comment: Perhaps you want `var obj = $(< package.json )`? The goal is to be reading from an input file, after all -- but since your heredoc sigil isn't quoted, you can use that kind of expansion there.

Comment: BTW, does `console.log` go to stdout or stderr? If the latter, you'll need to do a redirection to make sure it gets captured. Wouldn't hurt to wrap the whole thing in a command substitution for demonstrative purposes.

Comment: You're right for `$(< package.json )`; I saw your comment after my edit :)

Comment: *nod*. This is a good answer -- my only hesitancy in upvoting it is not being sure if its output can be captured with a command substitution on account of the stdout/stderr thing. Logging intended for human consumption *conventionally* goes to stderr, after all; if I had `node` installed I'd test, but...

Comment: Glad to have that confirmation.

Answer (score 1):

You can use also python one-liner

```sh
pkg_ver=$(
    python -c 'import sys,json; print(json.load(sys.stdin)["version"])' \
    < package.json
)
```

or even

```sh
pkg_ver=$(
    python -c 'import sys,json;print(json.load(open("package.json"))["version"])'
)
```

Comment: Better to take out the `cat` and use `<package.json` -- that way you have a direct handle on the input file rather than a FIFO connected to a separate process. See also http://porkmail.org/era/unix/award.html

Comment: @CharlesDuffy yeah, you are right! thanks :) I'll edit my answer

Comment: hmm, I'm also not sure `json.loads(open("foo"))` works, since `loads()` is to load a *string*. Do you mean `json.load(open(...))`?

Comment: @CharlesDuffy yeah, that was a typo :(

Comment: BTW, to support passing in a filename rather than hardcoding it, consider: `python -c 'import sys,json;print(json.load(open(sys.argv[1]))["version"])' "${1:-package.json}"` -- that way it isn't vulnerable to code injection attacks the way it could be if someone naively used `open("'"$1"'")` to modify your code to use a filename given as an argument.